MonkeyPatching python submodule
I want to monkey patch an external code base to check alternative versions of the same function.
At the moment, the project tree looks like this
.
├── mymodule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── myA.py
└── subProjectsDir
    └── subProject
        └── subonemodule
            ├── __init__.py
            └── subtwomodule
                ├── __init__.py
                ├── subA.py
                └── subthreemodule
                    ├── __init__.py
                    └── subB.py

In order to better reproduce the example on your machine, I uploaded the project in a zip file on my personal cloud storage space (here).
However, I'll keep the content of each file here.
Subproject
Let's start from the sub-project I need to fix. I put it inside the subProjectsDir/subProject directory.
subonemodule/__init__.py
from . import subtwomodule

subonemodule/subtwomodule/__init__.py
from .subA import funA

subonemodule/subtwomodule/subA.py
def funA():
    print("submoudle subA -> fun A")

This is the function I want to monkey patch
subonemodule/subtwomodule/subthreemodule/__init__.py
from .subB import funB

subonemodule/subtwomodule/subthreemodule/subB.py
from ...subtwomodule.subA import funA

def funB():
    print("subsubmoudle subB -> fun B")
    funA()

Note that this is the function called by my modules. This function in turn calls the function I need to patch. The import chain is, however, relative, which can maybe cause problems.
My Code
mymodule/__init__.py
import os
import sys
thisdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(thisdir, "..", "subProjectsDir", "subProject"))
print(f"From mymodule launch: {sys.path}")

The previous cose is used to use the subproject inside my code.
mymodule/myA.py
from subonemodule import subtwomodule
from subonemodule.subtwomodule import subA
from subonemodule.subtwomodule.subthreemodule.subB import funB

def myFunA():
    print("My A")

def main():
    # Monkey patch 1, not working
    # subA.funA = myFunA
    # Monkey patch 2, not working
    subtwomodule.subA.funA = myFunA
    funB()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The file contains my two attempts to monkey patch the function funA. To be more clear, the goal is that whenever the function funA is called from any module belonging to the sub-project, such call is replaced by a call to my funtion myFunA.
However, neither of the two approaches is working.
$> python3 -m mymodule.myA
sub3module subB -> fun B
sub2module subA -> fun A

Question
How should I proceed in this case? I was trying to not touch at all the external sub-project.

You need to patch the function before it's imported by you or any other module that you want the override to be visible to.
from subonemodule import subtwomodule

def myFunA():
    print("My A")

# patch funA before any other imports
subtwomodule.subA.funA = myFunA

from subonemodule.subtwomodule.subthreemodule.subB import funB


def main():
    funB()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Explanation
Printing the function addresses may help to understand what's happening.
Patching after import
this doesn't work
from subonemodule import subtwomodule
from subonemodule.subtwomodule.subthreemodule.subB import funB

def myFunA(): print("My A")

print("original funA", id(subtwomodule.subA.funA))
print("patched  funA", id(myFunA))

# patch funA
subtwomodule.subA.funA = myFunA

print("subB's   funA", id(subtwomodule.subthreemodule.subB.funA))

funB()

output:
original funA 4339032416
patched  funA 4338922368
subB's   funA 4339032416
sub3module subB -> fun B
sub2module subA -> fun A

sub2module was imported before funA was patched so it imported the original funA
Patching Before Import
from subonemodule import subtwomodule

def myFunA():print("My A")

print("original funA", id(subtwomodule.subA.funA))
print("patched  funA", id(myFunA))

# patch before importing
subtwomodule.subA.funA = myFunA
from subonemodule.subtwomodule.subthreemodule.subB import funB

print("subB's   funA", id(subtwomodule.subthreemodule.subB.funA))

funB()

output:
original funA 4330299744
patched  funA 4330189696
subB's   funA 4330189696
sub3module subB -> fun B
My A

funA was patched before it was imported by subB, so when subB is imported it only sees the patched funA.
